# Populate array of keys while joining with RethinkDb

Tags: rethinkdb, thinky

I wasn't able to populate a list of keys while joining on an other table so I was wondering if my models are correct and if what I'm trying to do is possible with Thinky, here is my code:

Group model

```
var Group = thinky.createModel('group', {
    users: [thinky.type.string()],
    place_id: thinky.type.string()
});
```

User model

```
var User = thinky.createModel('user', {
    name: thinky.type.string()
});
```

Place model

```
var Place = thinky.createModel('place', {
    name: thinky.type.string()
});
Place.hasMany(Group, "groups", "id", "place_id");
```

I'd like to fetch all the `groups` with user's name & place's name for a `place_id`

Here is what I've done:

```
Place.get(PLACE_ID).getJoin({groups: true}).then(function(g){console.log(g);});
```

How can I populate the user's name ? Using `_apply` ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer finally from the Thinky's owner :)

Thinky does join in a SQL way. See http://thinky.io/documentation/relations/

If a user can belong to multiple groups:

```
var Group = thinky.createModel('group', {
    id: thinky.type.string(),
    place_id: thinky.type.string()
});

var User = thinky.createModel('user', {
    id: thinky.type.string()
    name: thinky.type.string()
});

var Place = thinky.createModel('place', {
    name: thinky.type.string()
});

Place.hasMany(Group, "groups", "id", "place_id");

Group.hasAndBelongsToMany(User, 'users', 'id', 'id');

Place.get(PLACE_ID).getJoin({groups: {users: true}}).then(function(g){
    console.log(g);
})
```

Hope it helps.